# Objective C - Core Data relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationship

i've a problem with Core Data relationship.
I pass to my method addData an array of data. It is an array of dictionary. Every dictionary have 3 keys, "A", "B", "C". Key C store another array of dictionary that have 3 keys.
The first array is of item Type and the second of item Subtype.
Now, how can i place it into CoreData?The entity name is "Type" and "Subtype".
And how can i take it from CoreData?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an entity for `Type` which will have attributes `a` and `b` and a relationship `c` (lower case to conform with naming conventions).  `c` is a 1 to many relationship to the `Subtype` entity.  The Subtype entity has three attributes, one for each of the dictionary's keys and a relationship `type` which is the inverse relationship for the `Type` object's `c`.

Use the following pseudocode (I can't be bothered with the detail of setting up core data.  You can easily read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075)) to help you create a solution to populate your model from the original array of dictionaries.

```
for (NSDictionary* aType in typeArray)
{
    // Create a managed object for the dictionary called aTypeManagedObject

    [aTypeManagedObject setValue: [aType objectForKey: @"A"] forKey: @"a"];
    [aTypeManagedObject setValue: [aType objectForKey: @"B"] forKey: @"b"];

    for (NSDictionary* subType in [aType objectForKey: @"C"])
    {
        // Create a managed object for the dictionary called aSubtypeManagedObject

        // set the attributes in the same way as a and b above

        [aSubTypeManagedObject setValue: aType forKey: @"type"]; // Automatically updates the aType's c relationship
    }
}

// Save all the changes
```

Next time you fetch the Type managed object from the core data store, all that will be set up already.

```
[aTypeManagedObject valueForKey: @"c"]
```

will return an array of the subtype objects for that Type object.